# Using JMockit to mock autowired interface implementations

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, jmockit

We are writing JUnit tests for a class that uses Spring autowiring to inject a dependency which is some instance of an interface. Since the class under test never explicitly instantiates the dependency or has it passed in a constructor, it appears that JMockit doesn't feel obligated to instantiate it either.

Up until now we have been using SpringRunner to have Spring load mock dependencies for us, which works. Two things we don't like about this are 1) the Spring framework has to be loaded and initialized each time running the tests which is not exactly speedy, and 2) we are forced to explicitly create all mock dependencies as real classes, something which JMockit helps eliminate.

Here's a simplified example of what we're testing:

```
public class UnitUnderTest {

   @Autowired
   ISomeInterface someInterface;

   public void callInterfaceMethod() {

      System.out.println( "UnitUnderTest.callInterfaceMethod calling someInterface.doSomething");
      someInterface.doSomething();
   }

}
```

So, the question is, is there a way to have JMockit create a mock `someInterface`?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638911/mock-object-and-spring-annotations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JMockit will always instantiate a mocked interface (except in the case of a final mock field), but that only occurs in test code. It will not automatically inject the instance into code under test.

You would have to manually inject the mock instance. For example:

```
public class SomeTest
{
   @Autowired UnitUnderTest unitUnderTest;
   @Mocked ISomeInterface theMock; // created and assigned automatically

   @Test
   public void testSomeMethod()
   {
      Deencapsulation.setField(unitUnderTest, theMock);
      //proceed with unit test here
   }
}
```

`mockit.Deencapsulation` is a Reflection-based utility class that lets you invoke private methods, get/set fields, etc.

Comment: Just a note: since this answer was posted, JMockit has added support for automatic injection of mock objects into tested classes. In this example, replace `@Autowired` with `@Tested` and `@Mocked` with `@Injectable`.

Comment: Wow @Rogério! that's nice! JMockit is so powerful... I'm loving it!!

Comment: @Rogério Can jmockit coverage tool generate report for mockito? our legacy test code is with mockito. Any links is helpful.

Comment: @yuyue007 Yes, the coverage tool does not require the presence of jmockit.jar, although it's easier when it is present. You would need to use the "-javaagent:jmockit-coverage.jar" JVM initialization parameter (from the command line/IDE, or the Ant/Maven/Gradle build script). Detais in the [documentation page](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html).

Comment: @Rogério Cool! I meet some problem when using cascade mock with generic type, I have created an issue in github, could you help to check where am wrong, or if it's a bug. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` to explicitly inject your mocked `ISomeInterface` in your test case.

See [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#unit-testing)

Comment: This is a useful class to be sure. Still, having to explicitly create the mock defeats one of the main reasons for using JMockit in the first place.

Comment: This is super useful.  I create mocks by hand and had an autowired property in the class under test.  This allowed me to set the property in the test to the mock without editing the code under test!  Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

With the hints kindly provided above, here's what I found most useful as someone pretty new to JMockit: JMockit provides the `Deencapsulation` class to allow you to set the values of private dependent fields (no need to drag the Spring libraries in), and the `MockUp` class that allows you to explicitly create an implementation of an interface and mock one or more methods of the interface. Here's how I ended up solving this particular case:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

   IMarketMakerDal theMock = new MockUp <IMarketMakerDal>() {

      @Mock
      MarketMakerDcl findByMarketMakerGuid( String marketMakerGuid ) {

         MarketMakerDcl marketMakerDcl = new MarketMakerDcl();
         marketMakerDcl.setBaseCurrencyCode( CURRENCY_CODE_US_DOLLAR );
         return marketMakerDcl;
      }
   }.getMockInstance();

   setField( unitUnderTest, theMock );
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

For those people who met

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing @Injectable for field ***
```

or

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing @Tested class for field ***
```

error when using `jmockit` to mock `@autowired` field in `spring` ( or `spring boot`) framework, I did below two steps to avoid above errors:

1. use `@Tested(fullyInitialized=true)` instead of `@Tested`

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jmockit-users/uo0S51lSX24/lQhLNN--eJcJ

2. revert jmockit's version back to `1.18` or previous ones

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmockit-users/wMFZggsA8LM

Answer (score 2):

If you have a @Qualifier annotation for the interface, you need to name your @Injectable field exactly as it is named in qualifier.

Here is quote from [JMockit doc](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Tested.html):

> Custom names specified in field annotations from Java EE (@Resource(name), @Named) or the Spring framework (@Qualifier) are used when looking for a matching @Injectable or @Tested value. When such a name contains a - (dash) or . (dot) character, the corresponding camel-cased name is used instead.

For example:

```
@Component
public class AClass {

   @Autowired
   private Bean1 bean1;

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("my-dashed-name")
   private AmqpTemplate rpcTemplate;
}
```

Unit test class:

```
public class AClassTest {

   @Injectable
   private Bean1 bean1;

   @Injectable
   private AmqpTemplate myDashedName;

   @Tested
   private AClass aClass = new AClass();
}
```

Also there is no need to use setFiled for each @Autowired bean, all fields injects automatically when @Tested class instantiated. Tested on JMockit ver. 1.30