# Using @Autowired with JMockit makes the @Autowired object null

Tags: unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc, junit, jmockit

I realize that there is another SO question which deals with this exact problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1980596/1022)). However, it won't work in my case.

I have a maven (web/frontend) project using spring. I've added jmockit to the jvm through the pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/mockit/jmockit/0.998/jmockit-0.998.jar</argLine>
    <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The [SUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) (abbreviated) looks like:

```
@Service
@RequestMapping("/bars")
public class BarsController{
[...]
@Autowired
private FooUtils fooUtils;

[...]    
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getBars(){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    Session session = fooUtils.getSession();
[...]
```

Now, I would really like to mock out the `FooUtils` instance in my test. Following the advice given in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1980596/1022), I tried:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class BarsControllerTest {

@Autowired BarsController unitUnderTest;
@Mocked Session session;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    FooUtils foo = new MockUp <FooUtils>() {
        @Mock
        Session getSession() {
            return session;
        }
    }.getMockInstance();

    mockit.Deencapsulation.setField(unitUnderTest, foo);
}
```

Alas, the `unitUnderTest` as well as the `foo` are both `null`, causing this to happen:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.manniche.thebars.BarsControllerTest.setUp(BarsControllerTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
```

- Which is quite unexpected, as I would expect `new MockUp<...>{}.getMockInstance()` to return *some* object.

I guess that I'm just missing out on some crucial part, but which?

Comment: Why doesn't the solution in the other question work for you?

Comment: @skaffman: I wish I knew :) As I have stated in my question, the problem for me is, that the mocked object is null, which I neither expected or understand. The instructions given in the other question brought me this far, but no further. It solved the other guy's problem, for which I envy him, but I didn't want to continue the discussion in that question, as it was already solved (for his case)