# Using JMockit and Spring AOP together

Tags: java, junit, spring-aop, jmockit

Suppose I have a program that looks like this:

```
@Component
public class MainAction {
    public void doTheAction() {
        System.out.println("Now doing the action");
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class BeforeAspect {
    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    @Before("execution(* thepackagename.MainAction.*(..))")
    public void doBefore() {
        logger.log("The @Before advice has run");
    }
}

@Component
public class Logger {
    public void log(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

This is working fine if I run it through Eclipse (the main method esentially calls `mainAction.doTheAction()` after `mainAction` is created by Spring).

Now I want to write a test that ensures that the `log` method is called correctly when `doTheAction` is called.  We're using JMockit for our testing.  (This is a very simplified case of a problem I'm actually facing; a more complex logger is being called via an AOP aspect, and the wrong value of something is being logged.  Before working on a fix, I'm trying write a test to ensure the logged value is correct.)

This is what my (simplified) test currently looks like:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:Beans.xml"})
public class MainActionTest {
    @Tested
    private MainAction mainAction;

    @Test
    public void testThatLoggerIsCalled(@Injectable Logger logger) {
        new Expectations() { {
            logger.log(anyString);
        } };
        mainAction.doTheAction();
    }
}
```

The `@ContextConfiguration` may be useless.  Earlier I had tried `@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)`, which is why `@ContextConfiguration` is there, but none of the mocking stuff was handled.  Also, I'm using `@Tested` and `@Injectable` instead of `@Autowired` and `@Mocked`, following the suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980596/using-jmockit-to-mock-autowired-interface-implementations); without that, `mainAction` remained null.  So now the test runs, and `Now doing the action` appears in the output.  But `The @Before advice has run` doesn't appear (and doesn't appear even if I don't mock the `Logger`), and the expectation fails.

How can I use JMockit and AOP together?

**Edit:** As requested, I added something to print the classpath property.  Here it is (with unimportant parts of some path names removed):

```
Eclipse workspaces\springtest8\target\test-classes
Eclipse workspaces\springtest8\target\classes
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030\junit.jar
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
.m2\repository\org\jmockit\jmockit\1.18\jmockit-1.18.jar
.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar
.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.0.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar
.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.2.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.2.0.RELEASE\spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar
.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.2.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.8.6\aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.6\aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar
.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\4.2.0.RELEASE\spring-test-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar
/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/201/1/.cp/
/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/200/1/.cp/
```

**Edit 2:** I got things to work by removing JUnit4 from the Libraries tab in Configure Build Path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following test works fine, using Spring 3.0 or newer (tested with Spring 3.0.7, 4.0.5, and 4.2.0):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:beans.xml")
public class MainActionTest
{
    @Inject MainAction mainAction;

    @Test
    public void testThatLoggerIsCalled(@Mocked final Logger logger)
    {
        mainAction.doTheAction();

        new Verifications() {{ logger.log(anyString); }};
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting `Method testThatLoggerIsCalled should have no parameters`.  I'm using Spring 4.1.0--tried 4.2.0 also.  Also, Eclipse set up my JUnit to be 3.8.1--do I need a later version?  Are you using @Inject from `javax.inject`, or somewhere else?

Comment: This error about "have no parameters" does occur for me as well, but *only* if I use Spring 2.5, which is based on the old JUnit 4.4 test runner. The minimum JUnit version for both JMockit *and* Spring Test 4.1 is JUnit 4.5; it can't work with 3.8.1 (but that's probably something else - your junit.jar in the runtime classpath is most likely JUnit 4.x).

Comment: I'm accepting the answer so that the bounty doesn't expire.  But I'll keep trying to get the versions right, and I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse.  If I look in Configure Build Path, the entry for JUnit4 is C:\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030.  JUnit 3.8.1 is in a Maven dependency.  I updated pom.xml to use JUnit 4.11.  I've also tried putting JUnit4 both in front of, and behind, the Maven dependencies in the build path.  I have not gotten anything to work.

Comment: Check your actual runtime classpath by printing `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` to the console. Note that Eclipse has *two* lists of jars in the build path (why it does that I have no idea, as other IDEs have a single list), and it does not print the command line to the console when running tests, which makes it hard to find a classpath problem.

Comment: I've edited the question.  It's interesting that junit is in there twice (set up once by Eclipse, I assume, and once in the Maven repo), but they're both 4.11.  JUnit4 is currently below Maven Dependencies in "Order and Export"....  OK, I got it to work by removing JUnit4 from the Libraries tab entirely.

Comment: So it seems that, in this case, the suggestion in http://jmockit.org/gettingStarted.html to use Order and Export to order the jars wasn't good enough; I had to get rid of JUnit4 from this tab entirely, and list it only in Maven.  I think I've seen other stackoverflow questions that recommend this (not sure, I'll have to search for it).  But I didn't make the connection between my problem and whatever problem they were having.

Answer (score 3):

I never had to annotate JUnit tests with RunWith to use JMockit. From the [documentation](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Introduction.html#runningTests) you need to make sure the jmockit jar is loaded before junit's or add the javaagent jvm parameter. That way you'll be able to run the tests with Spring's Junit Runner and have JMockit as the mock framework.

Comment: Yes, this should work. I can only add that instantiation/injection of the class under test needs to be done by Spring, otherwise the aspect won't work. To mock the injected `Logger`, the test would have to use `@Capturing` instead of `@Injectable`.

Comment: It's not working for me.  I get `Method testThatLoggerIsCalled should have no parameters` (from inside SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java), which I don't get if I use `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`.  I'm using Maven dependencies, and I moved `jmockit` above `junit` in pom.xml (actually, `jmockit` is now first) and cleaned and rebuilt the project.  So what else did I forget to do?

Comment: @Rogério I still can't get it to work (see previous comment).

Comment: Now I'm thinking maybe I can get it to work without the method parameter.   (Will try tomorrow.)   (Originally, when I got the error, I assumed I couldn't use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` so I abandoned the idea.)  But it seems like maybe there are some JMockit features that will work without `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`, and some JMockit features that won't.  Is there a list of features that won't work?

Comment: I'm thinking any JMockit annotation won't work. You should mock classes using code instead.

Comment: All features of JMockit work without `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`, as long as the standard JUnit test runner is used; if using some other custom test runner (such as `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`) then it may or may not work, depending on how exactly that custom runner is implemented.