# JMockit with Spring autowire not working

Tags: java, spring, jmockit

I'm using JMockit to test a class which is being autowired (spring). From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980596/using-jmockit-to-mock-autowired-interface-implementations), i could understand that i will have to manually inject the mock instance to the ClassToBeTested. Even if i do this, i'm running into `NullPointerEx` at line `Deencapsulation.setField(classUnderTest, mockSomeInterface);` since both classUnderTest and mockSomeInterface are `null`. However if i use `@Autowire` on `mockSomeInterface`, it's being auto wired properly.

Class To Be tested:

```
@Service
public class ClassToBeTested implements IClassToBeTested {

 @Autowired
 ISomeInterface someInterface;

 public void callInterfaceMethod() {
  System.out.println( "calling interface method");
  String obj = someInterface.doSomething();
 }
}
```

Test Case:

```
public class ClassToBeTestedTest  {

@Tested IClassToBeTested classUnderTest;

@Mocked ISomeInterface mockSomeInterface;

public void testCallInterfaceMethod(){
  Deencapsulation.setField(classUnderTest, mockSomeInterface);
  new Expectations() { {
     mockSomeInterface.doSomething(anyString,anyString); result="mock data";     
  }};
 // other logic goes here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, using a recent version of JMockit (note the linked question is from 2010, and the library has evolved a lot since then):

```
public class ClassToBeTestedTest
{
    @Tested ClassToBeTested classUnderTest;
    @Injectable ISomeInterface mockSomeInterface;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        new Expectations() {{
            mockSomeInterface.doSomething(anyString, anyString); result = "mock data";
        }};

        // call the classUnderTest
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do this with a spring @Autowired field in the test class?